# How does destructor work?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to understand why do I get 3x~C(). I know the first 5 C() come from the first 2 declarations, the array declaration which uses the constructor 2 times, then another declaration. Afterward, why do I get 3 instead of 1 destructor call?

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class C
    {
    public:
        C() {cout<< "C() ";}
        ~C() {cout<< "~C() ";}
    private:
        int i;
    };

    int main(){
        C c1;
        C* p1= new C;
        {
           C c[2];
           C* p2 = new C;  
           delete p2;
        }
        C c[2];
        delete p1;
        return 0;
    }
    //C() C() C() C() C() ~C() ~C() ~C() C() C() ~C() ~C() ~C() ~C()
```

Comment: You did another `C c[2]` outside the `{}` block, before you do a `delete p1;` call, so that would give you 3 straight `~C()` calls.

Comment: Yes, but why do I get the 3x~C() prior to that?

Comment: Becouse the `{}` scope, when exiting that scope the `C[2]` stuff is deleted.

Comment: Just think how much better your life would be if you had a static variable incremented in each constructor and assigned to the constructed object - so that you know which constructor corresponds to which destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will break down the code and annotate it with the construction/destruction calls:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C
{
public:
    C() {cout<< "C() ";}
    ~C() {cout<< "~C() ";}
private:
    int i;
};

int main(){
    C c1; // C()
    C* p1= new C; // C()
    {
       C c[2]; // C() C() - because you constructed two C objects with this array
       C* p2 = new C;  // C()
       delete p2; // ~C()
    } // ~C() ~C() because the {} block ends, which means that local objects to that scope are destructed

    C c[2] ; // C() C() because you constructed two more
    delete p1; // ~C() because you're explicitly destructing
    return 0; // ~C() ~C() ~C() because of the c1 object and the c[2] array being destructed
}
```

So ultimately, this happens:

```
C() // c1 created
C() // p1 created
C() // c[2] created
C() // c[2] created
C() // p2 created
~C() // delete p2
~C() // c[2] in {} destroyed by end of scope
~C() // c[2] in {} destroyed by end of scope
C() // c[2] created
C() // c[2] created
~C() // delete p1
~C() // c[2] destroyed at end of program
~C() // c[2] destroyed at end of program
~C() // c1 destroyed at end of program
```

Comment: So it is not mandatory to use delete, since the memory is freed anyways at the end of the program/scope?

Comment: @user3201639 - At the end of a program, the OS will reclaim whatever memory you used, and scoping rules will destroy stack-allocated objects (as in, stuff on the stack). However, `new` allocates objects on the heap and returns a pointer/reference, so, for example, `p2` is a pointer (on the stack) but refers to an object in memory, When the scope `p2` is in ends, the pointer itself is cleaned up, but the memory it references isn't, so you should always `delete` things you `new`'ed when you don't need them anymore. Look into smart pointers as well like `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Yes, it is! Only those objects that were created non-dynamically (by **not** using `malloc` or `new`) are destroyed automatically. If you created an object using `new` you and only you are responsible for freeing its memory by using `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors get called when you delete an object pointer, or when a stack object goes out of scope. Here's what happens in your code line by line:

```
int main(){
    C c1;
    // C() (1 stack object created in main scope(a) )
    C* p1= new C;
    // C()
    {
       C c[2];
       // C() C() (2 stack objects created in inner scope)
       C* p2 = new C;  
       // C()
       delete p2;
       // ~C() 
    }
    // ~C() ~C() (the array of 2 objects went out of scope, so they got destructed)
    C c[2];
       // C() C() (2 stack objects created in main scope, (b) and (c))
    delete p1;
       // ~C() 
    return 0;
     // ~C() ~C() ~C() (3 stack objects destructed in main scope (a), (b) and (c))
}
```

You can understand what goes on better here if you change your class to keep a unique ID for each object:

```
class C
{
public:
    C() 
    : i (newID()) {
      cout<< "C#" << i << "()";
    }
    ~C() {
       cout<< "~C#" << i << "()";
    }
private:
    int newID() {
         static int counter = 0;
         return counter++;
    }

    const int i;
};
```

Output:

> C#0 C#1 C#2 C#3 C#4 ~C#4 ~C#3 ~C#2 C#5 C#6 ~C#1 ~C#6 ~C#5 ~C#0

Answer (score 0):

1. `C c1` ctr called 1 time

   - *(ctr: 1; dtr: 0)*
2. `C* p1= new C;` ctr called 1 time

   - *(ctr: 2; dtr: 0)*
3. `C c[2];` ctr called 2 times

   - *(ctr: 4; dtr: 0)*
4. `C* p2 = new C;`ctr called 1 time

   - *(ctr: 5; dtr: 0)*
5. `delete p2;` dtr called 1 time

   - *(ctr: 5; dtr: 1)*
6. `c` runs out of scope, dtr called 2 times

   - *(ctr: 5; dtr: 3)*
7. `C c[2];` ctr called 2 times

   - *(ctr: 7; dtr: 3)*
8. `delete p1;` dtr called 1 time

   - *(ctr: 7; dtr: 4)*
9. `c1` runs out of scope; dtr called 1 time

   - *(ctr: 7; dtr: 5)*
10. `c` runs otu of scope, dtr called 2 times

    - *(ctr: 7; dtr: 7)*

Now, wheres the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first 5 constructor calls are clear. Then there 3 destructor calls. The first `c` array was declared inside a block:

```
{
   C c[2]
   //...
} // objects in c are destroyed
```

When the block is left then all objects that were created non-dynamically inside the block are destroyed by calling their destructor. So there is the first destructor call from your `delete p2` and then two other destructor calls for destroying the two objects contained in the array. The same holds for the last four destructor calls at the end: the first destructor call os from your `delete p1` and the other three destructor calls are for the `C c[2]` that was declared outside the block and for destroying the `c1` object.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you understand that **any time a non-dynamically (malloc/new) heap-allocated object goes out of scope, it is destroyed!**

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class C
    {
    public:
        C() {cout<< "C() ";}
        ~C() {cout<< "~C() ";}
    private:
        int i;
    };

    int main(){
        C c1; // Construct c1
        cout << "--------------";
        C* p1= new C; // Construct p1
        {
           cout << "--------------";
           C c[2]; // Construct 2 objects c[2]
           cout << "--------------";
           C* p2 = new C;  // Construct p2
           cout << "--------------";
           delete p2; // Destruct p2
        } // Destructs 2 objects c[2]
        cout << "--------------";
        C c[2]; // builds 2 objects
        cout << "--------------";
        delete p1;
        // p1 is destructed
        return 0;
    } // two objects in c[2] are destructed, c1 is also destructed
```

http://ideone.com/xlVUXm

Output:

```
C() --------------C() --------------C() C() --------------C() --------------
~C() ~C() ~C() --------------C() C() --------------~C() ~C() ~C() ~C()
```